# Deserialize object from string

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I'm trying to deserialize object from string, but get "no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('test')" exception.

```kotlin
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.readValue
import io.kotest.core.spec.style.FunSpec
import io.kotest.matchers.shouldBe

class KotlinJacksonTest : FunSpec({

    val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()

    test("deserialize as string") {
        class Ref @JsonCreator constructor(@JsonValue val name: String)
        class Root(val ref: Ref)

        val root = mapper.readValue<Root>(""" { "ref": "test"} """)
        root.ref.name shouldBe "test"
    }
})
```

What I need is to make jackson serialize my object as if it was a string.
But it constantly fails with the following error:

```
Cannot construct instance of `KotlinJacksonTest$1$1$Ref` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('test')
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `KotlinJacksonTest$1$1$Ref` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('test')
 at [Source: (String)" { "ref": "test"} "; line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: KotlinJacksonTest$1$1$Root["ref"])
```

What I'm doing wrong? I can clearly remember this worked for me in java when I needed to do same but with map instead of string.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after reading some documentation on JsonCreator annoation turns out that it must be like this:

```kotlin
class Ref @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.DELEGATING) constructor(@JsonValue val name: String)
```

The `JsonCreator.Mode.DELEGATING` makes it work like I wanted.

**UPD**: There is even a possibility to make it shorter - custom jackson annotation.

```kotlin
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CONSTRUCTOR)
@JacksonAnnotationsInside
@JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.DELEGATING)
annotation class JsonDelegating
```

And usage:

```kotlin
class Ref @JsonDelegating constructor(@JsonValue val name: String)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid having to annotate the constructor of your data class completely by just targeting the `@JsonValue` annotation on your property to its getter method, like so:

```
class Ref(@get:JsonValue val name: String)
```

Notably `@field:JsonValue` does *not* work in this case either.

Why your original code, nor the field targeting, do not work as expected, I couldn't tell you.